# Custom Warehouse

Tags: magento2, product, stock, order-status

By Default Magento using Total Stock warehouse. I want to use my warehouse for all my products . I am currently using my custom warehouse, But some times it shows the magento by default warehouse.

Answer (score 0):

It was the custom extension that cause the issue. I debug it and fix it.